# System Error when getting a value from a database using WCF (IIS 7.5)

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, wcf, xamarin

I have an Android Application which connects to a database through WCF service hosted in IIS 7.5. I based it from here: [Walkthrough - Working with WCF](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/). I'm only using my localhost and I haven't configured the remote access. The problem is every time I click the button (which upon clicking will pass the value of the inputted number then process the sql statement then it will return the result which will appear in the textview beside the button), a dialog box appears saying `System Error`. I am running this app in Android emulator which should be fine since I only connect through a localhost.

Here are my codes:

MainActivity.cs

```
btnCheck = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imageButton1);
btnCheck.Click += GetEmployeeDataOnClick;

private void InitializeEmployeeServiceClient()
{
    BasicHttpBinding binding = CreateBasicHttp();
    _client = new EmployeeServiceClient(binding, EndPoint);
    _client.DisplayEmployeeCompleted += ClientOnDisplayEmployeeCompleted;
}

private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttp()
{
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
    {
        Name = "basicHttpBinding",
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
    };
    TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
    binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
    binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
            return binding;
}

private void GetEmployeeDataOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    empNumber = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
    EmployeeNo employee = new EmployeeNo();
    employee.EmpNo = empNumber.Text;
    _client.DisplayEmployeeAsync(employee);
}

private void ClientOnDisplayEmployeeCompleted(object sender, DisplayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs)
{
    empName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView9);
    string msg = null;
    if (displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs.Error != null)
    {
         msg = displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs.Error.Message;
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.SetMessage(msg);
         alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) => {});
         RunOnUiThread(() => {
                    alert.Show();});
    }
    else if (displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled)
    {
         msg = "Request was cancelled.";
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.SetMessage(msg);
         alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) => {});
         RunOnUiThread(() => {
                    alert.Show();
                });
    }
    else
    {
         msg = displayEmployeeCompletedEventArgs.Result;
         RunOnUiThread(() => empName.Text = msg);

    }
}
```

IService.cs (WCF)

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEmployeeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string DisplayEmployee(EmployeeNo empNo);
}

[DataContract]
public class EmployeeNo
{
    string empNumber = string.Empty;

    [DataMember]
    public string EmpNo
    {
        get { return empNumber; }
        set { empNumber = value; }
    }

}
```

Service.svc.cs (WCF)

```
public string DisplayEmployee(EmployeeNo empNo)
{
    // sql connection, statement (inputted empNo which corresponds to an EmpName)
    return EmpName;
}
```

Am I doing this correctly? What is the problem here?
*I am a total newbie here btw.*

Comment: What IP are you connecting to from your Android device?

Comment: Make sure you are connecting to your Window's machine IP address and not using `localhost` within the Android app (`localhost` within the Android app is the Android device)

Comment: @Matt I'm using Android emulator. Do I need to set anything on the emulator? Because I'm connecting through a localhost.

Comment: In your emulator go to Settings > About phone -> Status there you see your Android emulator has another IP. Most emulators create a virtual network device with a local (on your pc) network.

Comment: @SushiHangover Should I change the localhost into a specific IP address? Will the android device be connected on the specified address automatically? Because I just checked what Matt said and it's really using a different IP.

Comment: At first, I used a specific IP address but my IP usually changes depending on which network I am connecting, so it's a hassle to change it every time.

Comment: Within the Android app, you can use 10.0.3.2 or 10.0.2.2 to "reach" your Windows host as this is mapped to the loopback address of the host. Different emulator set different subnets, but try 10.0.3.2 first, the then other. This address will not change unless your switch to a different emulator

Comment: The easier test is to have an open status html page on your web server, open the web browser in the emulator and surf to your machine's IP.

Answer (score 2):

Change the IP addess to connect to your IIS to the actual IP address of your server (the host of your emulator in this case).

You can also use the hostname like "http://user-pc:8080/DataService".

Comment: I can now connect to the database from the emulator. What I did is changed localhost into the actual IP address and configured the remote access to IIS Express. I tried accessing it on my Android phone but I couldn't connect unlike on the Android emulator. I am connecting my Android phone in the same network so why I am getting the `System Error`?

Comment: What if it's connected to a different network? How should I make it still accessible if the user is connected to a different IP address? Sorry for these many questions, it's still confusing me as this is my first time doing this.

Comment: Well for different addresses it's not so easy. If it's always the same computer, try the computername instead of IP - but this might not work in any case. Also check you firewall settings.